# Complex update multiple rows with Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have to make update on Entity Framework Core on multiple rows.

I have 2 tables: ProjectStep and StepDefinition. ProjectStep has ProjectStepId, ParentStepId(pointing to ProjectStep table) and StepDefinitionId. StepDefinition has StepDefinitionId and ParentStepId(pointing to StepDefinition table). I need to update ParentStepId in the table ProjectStep based on the values in StepDefinition  Here is how I would have done it in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE  ps
SET     ParentStepId=ps1.ProjectStepId         
FROM    ProjectStep ps INNER JOIN
        StepDefinition sd ON ps.StepDefinitionId = sd.StepDefinitionId INNER JOIN
        ProjectStep AS ps1 ON sd.ParentStepId = ps1.StepDefinitionId and ...
```

and in SQL Server this works like a charm. How do I do this in Entity Framework Core? Wirh Linq preferably.
Thanks

Comment: It isn't possible with EF Core to generate this sql update. You can execute your custom sql with [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Database_ExecuteSqlCommand_System_String_System_Object___) or update in C# script.

Comment: yes but if I make changes in the database I should reload the data in Entity Framework

Comment: Linq is for querying. CUD in EF Core is performed using load/modify/save pattern, so no equivalent of SQL DML either. This is out of the box. There are some 3rd party packages which can do what you are asking for. But since it is not supported out of the box, not sure what are their limitations (for instance, supported databases etc.)

Comment: But if you need to "reload data" afterwards anyway, just use the EF Core approach (load/modify in memory/save changes).

Comment: Ivan Stoev I want to do "Modify in memory" but I have to put multiple for cycles that I'm trying to avoid